# Open Graph Beta / Meta Tags

Tags: meta-tags, open-graph-beta

do you have to add og meta tags manually to each webpage? I have a website that has lots of seperate articles and I need a way to automatically create the og tags

Thanks

Comment: See here how to dynamically generate og meta tags: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8431694/601466

Answer (score 1):

If your articles are generated by a server side programming language, you could programmatically add the meta tags into the code which outputs the other article information

If they're individual HTML files you'll have to add them manually or write a script to insert them into your pages