# Generating Facebook Open Graph meta tags dynamically

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

As the title implies I'm trying to generate Facebook Open Graph meta tags dynamically, but I can't get it working. Is it even possible?

## UPDATE:

Finally I got it working with the help of @saccharine. The following code is working for me:

```
<?php

$params = array();
if(count($_GET) > 0) {
    $params = $_GET;
} else {
    $params = $_POST;
}
// defaults
if($params['type'] == "") $params['type'] = "restaurant";
if($params['locale'] == "") $params['locale'] = "en_US";
if($params['title'] == "") $params['title'] = "default title";
if($params['image'] == "") $params['image'] = "thumb";
if($params['description'] == "") $params['description'] = "default description";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# MY_APP_NAME_SPACE: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/MY_APP_NAME_SPACE#">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

        <!-- Open Graph meta tags -->
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_APP_ID" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="meta site name"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com/index.php?type=<?php echo $params['type']; ?>&locale=<?php echo $params['locale']; ?>&title=<?php echo $params['title']; ?>&image=<?php echo $params['image']; ?>&description=<?php echo $params['description']; ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="MY_APP_NAME_SPACE:<?php echo $params['type']; ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:locale" content="<?php echo $params['locale']; ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $params['title']; ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/img/<?php echo $params['image']; ?>.png"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $params['description']; ?>"/>

    </head>
</html>
```

The url I'm putting into the Facebook debugger now can include any of the dynamic parameters or even none, all or only a selection and in any order like so:
http://mysite.com/index.php?type=restaurant&title=luigis
or this:
http://mysite.com/index.php?locale=de_DE&description=hi&type=bistro

Having that accomplished: I can now publish actions to the user's stream:

```
function postRestaurant() {
    FB.api('me/MY_APP_NAMESPACE:have_lunch?\
    start_time=2000-12-12T04:00:00&\
    expires_in=7200&\
    restaurant=' + encodeURIComponent(getRedirectURI() + '?type=restaurant' + '&description=arnold' + '&title=stalone'), 'post', function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log('postRestaurant: Error occured => ' + response.error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('postRestaurant: Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

Works like a charm! : ]

Comment: Like you, I am able to generate dynamic meta tags by calling the URL to my object with GET/POST parameters from the debugger, but have you figured out how to implement something similar with your app? So far, when I use the Javascript SDK to try and post an action, and include the parameters in the URL to my object (like I would in the debugger) Facebook appears to strip out those parameters so that my object page (index.php for you) never recieves them. Any ideas?

Comment: @bradleygriffith Yes, I have managed to post actions to the user's stream. I have updated my question once again with an example on how to do it with the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: I ran into same problem. How exactly did you solve this? How id you explain facebook to read the full URL with all params?

Comment: I always get this error: Object at URL 'http://www.mydomain.com/object/?og:type' of type 'website'

Comment: Whenever I use this code for different objects. I get the error: "(#3502) Object at URL http://mywebsite/testing.php?type=goal&action=start&title=Hurra&image=car&description=Test has og:type of 'woadeapp:baby'. The property 'goal' requires an object of og:type 'woadeapp:goal'.  (http response code: 206)

Comment: @Lego It almost works for me, but I always got default values in meta properties when I make a post via Facebook Graph API Explorer. What could it be?

Comment: @Lego forgive thy humble student: I am assuming since the task is simply addresses generating og tags that I don't need to worry where I stick this? just toss it in and stir? also, I'm trying to use this with a tumblr php caching app that presents my tumblr as a native blog on my website, could you poin out what I need to change in your code? I am happy to experiment but want to avoid breaking anything...

Comment: @jordanconductor You should always put the og tags to the top of the document head, so that the Facebook bot can easily crawl them. Also, if you want to experiment without breaking anything, do so by using the Facebook [debug tool](developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: @Lego, thanks and I use /debug almost hourly it feels like. I do have go tags in the head. What ends up happening is that right now, all dynamically generated pages at /blog/post-123456 are inheriting the og tags of /blog. E.g. the og:title of an individual post is "blog" and more importantly, that the canonical og:url is /blog. I'm going to work with Support from the guys that built it, but this is the closest thing I've found to an option if you can identify any of the useful bits in there that I'd need to change.

Comment: Can anybody please help me doing it using JQuery. My requirement is exactly the same, but I have no idea about PHP.

Comment: @AryanVenkat It's impossible to do with client side code because the facebook scraper does not execute any JavaScript code before parsing your site.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, I want to reiterate that I am almost positive that your problem is due to the fact that the url you are passing into the debugger is not dynamically generated. The url tag essentially acts as a redirector. Unless it's the exact same (meaning the meta tags on the url meta object is the same as those on the url you are passing in) as the url you are testing, you won't get the results you're looking for.

The meta tag

```
<meta property="og:url">
```

needs to be dynamically generated. The debugger is being redirected to your default index page instead of the dynamically generated page.

For example, I assign an id to every object I'm using, and so I have something like the following

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/index.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>"/>
```

I pass in that exact url into the debugger, and thus the final page the debugger lands on will be that exact url.

Also, in the following

```
<meta property="og:type" content=""/>
```

how is the property being dynamically generated? Did you remember to set in your actual code something like the following?

```
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php echo $_GET['type'] ?>"/>
```

You also appear to be shoving everything into the url, which is dangerous and can cause huge headaches, which might be the issue here. Instead, shove only one thing , eg ?type=bistro and then propagate the necessary data from the DB.

I would recommend dynamically generating most OG tags based on an object_id. Store the relevant OG info for every object_id, and then propagate them when accessed. This way, you can also easily expand and edit the tags you use when OG is updated.

If you have problems with OG you shouldn't hesitate to post them as new questions instead of comments as I guarantee other people also have the same problem.

Comment: @Lego Right now I'm dynamically generating my meta tags with something I'm currently working on, and it's been working fine. Can I see how you're passing in the url property? For example, in your code example, you actually didn't include the passed in parameters explicitly. I've revised my answer to expand more on this.

Comment: @Lego The debugger will continue to ignore all your parameters as long as the url object is not dynamic and points to your parameterless index page like the way you have it set up right now. Can you post the meta tags when you view the source of the url you are passing into the debugger?

Comment: Thanks a ton! I would upwote you ten times if I could! I was almost believing it is not even posible but you made me try and try over again. You were right with the dynamic url and finally it works! I have updated my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8431694/601466) above.

Comment: @Lego glad I could help. You can also accept my question as the answer to give me even more internet points :D. Just click the check box underneath the upvote sign.

Comment: @saccharine It almost works for me, but I always got default values in meta properties when I make a post via Facebook Graph API Explorer. What could it be?

Comment: @deko FB has updated their stuff recently, so I'm not even sure if my stuff still applies. There's a ton of possible reasons. Without more info it's impossible to tell. What does the fb debugger say about your page? It sounds like you're not generating the proper dynamic tags.

Comment: @saccharine Thank you for your answer! I've solved my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378534/facebook-post-with-parameters#comment21736579_15378534

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly certain Facebook no longer crawls *any* urls with parameters.  It always "redirects" to a stripped version of the url.

In OPs example:

http://example.com/index.php?type=restaurant&title=luigis

becomes

http://example.com/index.php

regardless of what you do.  Closest thing I've seen to an explanation is [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags):

```
A URL with no session id or extraneous parameters. All shares on Facebook will use this as the identifying URL for this article.
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, works like a charm, but needs some recoding for me.  I have had to create a new page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# MY_APP_NAME_SPACE: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/MY_APP_NAME_SPACE#">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

        <!-- Open Graph meta tags -->
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?= urldecode($_GET['title']) ?>" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?= "http://www.calsots.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?= $_GET['image'] ?>" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Calsots.com" />
        <meta property="fb:admins" content="MY_APP_ID" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?= urldecode($_GET['description']) ?>" />

    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click the Get Code link in your object types, did you try pasting the code it gave you?

I would try pasting to your web, and then if it works, replicate the html output.

Try it without the DOCTYPE tag.

Heres a sample of what I got, and I dont see these tags above: fb:app_id, not sure if it makes a difference.

Also, shouldnt the og:url also include the variables at the end?

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="1234567888">
  <meta property="og:url"         content="http://mysite.com/index.php?type=MY_APP_NAMESPACE%3Abistro">

Answer (score 0):

For Joomla Opengraph Meta dynamic:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=
$title = $this->getTitle();
?>" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?= "http://YORUWEBSITE.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://YOURWEBSITE.com/images/stories/BIGIMAGE.jpg" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="YOURWEBSITE.com" />
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOURFACEBOOKAPPIDNUMBER" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?= $title = $this->getDescription(); ?>" />
```

Comment: You can probably apply this same approach to SMARTY as well.