# AddThis - Posting a variable score to Facebook and Twitter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, addthis

Is it possible to have facebook and twitter "AddThis" links pull a user's score from a game?

Im developing a simple HTML5 "quiz". There is a score counter set up that I would like to be able to echo to the Twitter and Facebook share options, but I cant seem to make this work and im not sure if it's even possible...

The counter is handled through JS and displays dynamically in "#score":

```
<div id="score-counter"><span id="score"></span<span>/20</span></div>
```

I would like to be able to share something like "I got '__'/20 on this game, can you beat me?"

Looked through a ton of documentation but still can't seem to figure it out... Can anyone advise how to go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the open graph is essentially a page scraper, you can't dynamically generate meta tags via javascript.  Essentially, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8877506/339698) is probably the right one which will ultimately lead  you to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431694/generating-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags-dynamically).

You would basically need to create a separate share url where you'd pass in query parameters for the page to read in order to dynamically spit out the correct meta tags for the open graph to see.