# How to publish Actions to Facebook Graph API with parameters in call URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

To begin, Ive spent several hours looking for an answer and have come CLOSE but havent found a full answer.

So Im trying to publish actions using Facebook's Graph API and want to send parameters in the URL when initially calling it with the Facebook Javascript SDK.

Here is a call that WORKS:

```
  function postNewAction()
  {
          passString = '&object=http://mysite.com/appnamespace/object.php';

          FB.api('/me/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION' + passString,'post',
             function(response) {
                  if (!response || response.error) {
                      alert(response.error.message);
                  } 
                  else {
                      alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                  } 
              }
          );    
   }
```

With object.php looking like so:

```
  <head xmlns:enemysearch="http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/ns#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID" /> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="APP_NAMESPACE:object" /> 
    <meta property="og:title" content="some title" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="some description"/> 
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com/appnamespace/object.php"/>
  </head>
```

So obviously the above will post some sort of action to Facebook that will be the same every time object.php is called.

This is not ideal for my purposes.

So I took a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431694/dynamic-generation-of-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags) and it helped but as you will see, doesnt answer everything.

So if I change object.php to include dynamically generated meta tags by using content from either GET or POST and use the [Object Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) with a matching URL format to the one provided in og:url, the debugger shows everything as working as I would expect with now warnings. Here is what the dynamically generated object.php looks like:

```
   <?php
      if(count($_GET) > 0) {
     $userName = (int)$_GET['userName'];
      }
      else {
     $userName = (int)$_POST['userName'];
      }
   ?>
  <head xmlns:enemysearch="http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/ns#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID" /> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="APP_NAMESPACE:object" /> 
    <meta property="og:title" content=" <?php echo $userName; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Click to view more from <?php echo $userName; ?>"/> 
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com/appnamespace/object.php?userName=<?php echo $userName; ?>"/>
  </head>
```

SO, what I need to know is how to send url parameters in the initial call. If I use the debugger and enter something to the effect of http://mysite.com/appnamespace/object.php?userName=Brad everything works fine and the meta tags return content with that name inside of them. However if I try to pass the same url in the Javascript Call, it returns an error saying that my meta property og:type needs to be 'APP_NAMESPACE:object' (which as you see above, is what I have) instead of 'website' (which as you can see above, is something I am not using). Here is what that broken call would look like:

```
  function postNewAction(userName)
  {
      passString = '&object=http://mysite.com/appnamespace/object.php?userName=' + userName;

      FB.api('/me/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION' + passString,'post',
         function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                  alert(response.error.message);
              } 
              else {
                  alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
              } 
          }
      );    
  }
```

To be clear, the userName variable is only for example.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tested it but i see something different from the code examples in this link

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#publish

In your code `passString` should start with `?` as is the very beginning of the query string.

```
// so this :
passString = '&object=http://mysite.com/appnamespace/object.php?userName=' + userName;
// should be :
passString = '?object=http://mysite.com/appnamespace/object.php?userName=' + userName;

  FB.api('/me/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION' + passString,'post',
     function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
              alert(response.error.message);
          } 
          else {
              alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
          } 
      }
  );
```