# Custom message facebook share button

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-sharer

I want a custom facebook share button that I could edit the message inside it everytime based on the users choice throughout the page.

Trick point is that this message is not static, should be dynamic and I have been working on meta tags for share button but couldnt manage to get what I want with them.

How can I do that?

EDIT: Code...

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Event Based Social Media" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="This is a test message from a project that connects people by creating events and notify them. Developers #METUNCC Aral, Atik, Cem, Izzet." /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.socialmedianews.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/social-media-crime-event-sydney-ark-group-australia-june-28-29-worldsquare-rydges-sydney.png" />



 <a name='fb_share' type='button_count' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?appId={YOUR APP ID}&link=<?php the_permalink() ?>' rel='nofollow'>Share</a><script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have sofar?

Comment: This works but as I said I cannot make it dynamic... Tried the editing meta tags from C# codebehind but didnt work either.

Comment: Try looking at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504176/can-facebook-open-graph-objects-be-created-dynamically)

Comment: any solution besides the above one?