# adding new object graph objects to facebook via app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an app that will allow people to share cycling routes that they have created within the Android app.

When the user saves the route, it should appear on their timeline as  created  using

I have added a page representing a route object on my heroku app server with sample meta-data. The problem is that it is only one page so any route uploaded has the same sample name that is contained in the route html file.

I guess I need to create a new HTML page for each route that is uploaded and then submit that to facebook but I don't know an easy way to do that.

Will I have to get my Android app to create a new HTML page, fill in the meta-data then upload this to the heroku server?

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is the HTML page I am using:

```
<?php

$params = array();
if(count($_GET) > 0) {
    $params = $_GET;
} else {
    $params = $_POST;
}
// defaults
if($params['title'] == "") $params['title'] = "Route";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# APP_NAME_SPACE: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/APP_NAME_SPACE#">
    <title></title>        
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <!-- Open Graph meta tags -->
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID" /> 
    <meta property="og:type"   content="APP_NAME_SPACE:route" /> 
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://APP_NAME.herokuapp.com/route.html?title=<?php echo $params['title']; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $params['title']; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:image"  content="LINK_TO_IMAGE" />
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: You don’t have to create a _physical_ .html file on the server – you can just as easily use some server-side script that gets an id value or something else passed, looks up the route data in the database, and outputs the according HTML code containing the appropriate OG meta tags on the fly.

Comment: I found a post on this site that might be doing what you suggest. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431694/dynamic-generation-of-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags`

I have tried to follow this. When using the debugger I get an error saying "Could not retrieve data from URL."

I'll post my html page representing a route in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Found this tutorial which has a good example of setting up dynamic objects:

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/
```