# Sharing buttons in a HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, button, sharing, social-media

I am creating a website with HTML, CSS, JS, etc... But I am not using Wordpress and I am not sure how can I add buttons to share news like you do with social sharing plugins in Wordpres. Anybody knows any Jquery plugin or method?

Thanks

Comment: this is easily researched in google

Comment: Thing is that I find many ways to do it in google, but I don´t know how to make them share the title and picture of each one of the pages I try to share. They all just share my url with the general title I give them and they don´t include photo.

Comment: you need to include open graph meta tags

Answer (score 0):

To show the title and photo you want, you need to use the open graph protocols.
This is a meta tag that tells facebook (or other social media) how to display your website.

```
<head>
  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Example Title" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="This is a description of the page I'm sharing..." />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg" />
</head>
```

You can create a share button [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) (for facebook), [here](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons) (for Twitter) and [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/) (for Google Plus).
Just google for other social media buttons.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful. Is there any way to match the Open graph protocols with some id of a <p> tag so I don´t need to rewrite it again every time?

Comment: If you want do add it dynamically check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431694/generating-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags-dynamically