# Google+ Snippet with Open Graph Protocol

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-plus, facebook-opengraph

I have a web page that is dynamically built and am trying to get links that are shared on Google+ to show snippets and look nice, an example snippet for article rendering and documentation can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/article-rendering

When I follow the documentation my links do not render with everything I set in google plus, they show up like this:

[image]

The head of my page looks like this:

```
<head>
<div id="replaceGoogle"></div>
</head>
```

In my javascript I have this to insert the open graph tags once generated:

```
//replace google
        var google = '<meta property="og:type" content="article" /><meta itemprop="og:headline" content="'+ data[0].name+'" /> <meta itemprop="og:description" content="View beer on Beer Portfolio" /> <meta property="og:image" content="'+ data[0].icon +'" />';
        $("#replaceGoogle").replaceWith(google);
```

The data is taken from json read in from an ajax call. Can I not do this dynamically?

Comment: Just ServerSide scripting that needs a dynamic your web language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that question is similar to [Generating Open Graph meta tags dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431694/generating-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags-dynamicall). The main reason of your problem is that google+ and facebook will not execute your javascript so none of them will see your dynamic og tags.

Basic solution to this problem is :

- create unique url for each dynamic page and save dynamic params for this url into database.
- when your user try to share pages with this unique url you will find saved dynamic params
- create page with og tags filled with found dynamic params

[image: Simple schema for saving og tags for dynamic generated pages]

Answer (score 1):

Use server side scripting (ask for details in the comments)