# How to Exclude Jumbotron Image from Social Media Thumbnail?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, thumbnails

Whenever my blog post is shared, the thumbnail is automatically the jumbotron image first instead of defaulting to the blog post image:

[image]

[image]

**view**

```
<%= image_tag "galli-walking.jpg", alt: "Conquering life and goal challenges so we can get the most out of life.", class: "main-image" %>
<div class="blog-text">
  <div class="blog-paragraph">
    A DAILY BLOG ABOUT MY<br>
    JOURNEY & LIFESTYLE
  </div>
  <%= render 'subscribes/subscribe.html.erb' %>
</div>
<%= link_to @post.title, blog_path(@post) %>
<%= simple_format(@post.body, {}, {:sanitize => false}) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this tag to `<head></head>`

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= image_path('your_image') %>" />
```

Possible solution to exclude image from using by share is to use div with CSS background-image property. Instead

```
<%= image_tag "galli-walking.jpg", alt: "Conquering life and goal challenges so we can get the most out of life.", class: "main-image" %>
```

use

```
<div style="background-image: url('galli-walking.jpg'); width:Xpx; height:Xpx;></div>
```

Comment: The image changes every blog post so you know a way I can just exclude `"galli-walking.jpg"` or dynamically reference the changing blog post image via setting a class or id?

Comment: I tried `<div style="background-image: url('http://www.anthonygalli.com/assets/galli-walking-a93de43b05a7e6485640332450ff259f.jpg'); width: 100%; position: relative;"></div>` Those are the attributes in `main-image`, but the image isn't showing on the web page now.

Comment: You need to specify height of `<div>`

Answer (score 2):

Read more from these articles. All you need is to dynamically generate Facebook Open Graph meta tag like so.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

https://blog.kissmetrics.com/open-graph-meta-tags/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

[Generating Facebook Open Graph meta tags dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431694/generating-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags-dynamically)

Comment: Is there a way I can exclude `og:image` from being `"http://www.anthonygalli.com/assets/galli-walking-a93de43b05a7e6485640332450ff259f.jpg"`?

Comment: I am searching for this one. Haven't tried before :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea to block this specific image (Warning: Untested and I am pretty sure it is far from best practise ;)

Add this rule to robots.txt file on your server:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /Path/to/galli-walking.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

When you share website content on social media like Facebook, Twitter etc they look for meta tags in the **head** section of your markup to pull information  like title, description, image etc. If you want it to use a different set of attributes, you need to provide dynamic values to meta tags like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<%= title %>">
<meta property="og:description" content="<%= description %>">
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= image_url %>">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="<%= width %>">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="<%= height %>">
```

and you need to provide value to these variables depending on the page you're rendering.

og = open graph

You can read more about it [here](http://ogp.me/).

Hope this helps.